# Request a Delivery Receipt and Read Receipt using System.Net.Mail

Tags: .net, smtpclient, system.net.mail

We are using System.Net.Mail namespace in our application to send emails to the users.
Is there a way we can request a delivery receipt and read receipt options when sending emails using the above namespace (also without using any third party libraries)?

Answer (score 13):

```
  MailMessage SendMail = new MailMessage();
        //other code to configure to, from, subject, body etc...
  //for read receipt
  SendMail.Headers.Add ("Disposition-Notification-To", "email@gmail.com"); 
  //for delivery receipt
  SendMail.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess
```